# adding a string to a string variable in batch

Tags: string, batch-file

```
set mail=backups:
set mail=%mail%"|pc1-OK"
set mail=%mail%"|pc2-OK"
set mail=%mail%"|pc3-OK"
set mail=%mail%"|pc4-OK"

blat.exe -to a@test.comt -f b@test.com -server 172.x.x.x -s "test" -body %mail%
```

gives me an email with the body:

```
backups:
pc1-OK"
pc2-OK
pc3-OK
pc4-OK
```

Why is there a " after the first PC?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how does blat internally work, i can not answer why there is only one quote in the output.

But, this is how it should be written

```
set "mail=backups:"
set "mail=%mail%|pc1-OK"
set "mail=%mail%|pc2-OK"
set "mail=%mail%|pc3-OK"
set "mail=%mail%|pc4-OK"

blat.exe -to a@test.comt -f b@test.com -server 172.x.x.x -s "test" -body "%mail%"
```